# run same project in parallel using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, instances

I have a java project under eclipse. since it produces different results any time it's launched, I have to launch it like hundreds of times and collect the results. is there any way to launch the same project in parallel? like 10 instances per time... that would spare me lots of time.

Comment: 1. Do you actually need several instances to actually run in parallel? Or do you just need to automate starting it multiple times? 2. Do the instances generate uniquely named output files? Or is everything going  to `System.out`. 3. Does each run have the same arguments?

Comment: several instances to run in parallel. so every instance prints me on the system.out a different output. (they are like randomized tests over a network of nodes, every "experiment" gives me a network behaviour report, so some of them just take seconds to finish, others take minutes). yes, each run have same arguments (every ten runs I have to change them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "brute force" solution: launch it once then just press the Run (or Debug) toolbar item repeatedly to quickly launch as many instances as you want. That's assuming you have enabled in the Preferences **Run/Debug** > **Launching** > **Launch Operation** > *Always launch the previously launched application*.

Comment: thank you. doing this, I always see the same project restarting in the console :(

Comment: nevermind. it worked (I didn't see the "remove launch" button). thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper application that simply calls the `main(String [])` method of your application a bunch of times, each on a different thread. You could even make this "wrapper" take as an argument the number of threads to spawn.

A downside is that all of the threads will write to the same sysout console, so depending on how you are supposed to gather "results" that might or might not be a problem.

Comment: I don't have a main class... I'm using a framework and above this framework I have some classes (with no main) that framework takes as "arguments"

Comment: Somewhere, something has a `main()`, which must be called by your current launch configuration. Whether it's from your code or a framework doesn't really matter.